# JsonSerializer deserialize as simple type

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, deserialization, system.text.json

My JSON looks like this. Values can only be numeric, string or null:

```
attributes: {
    "value1": "name",
    "value2": 123,
    "value3": null
}
```

When deserializing, the values in the dictionary are deserialized as JsonElements.

Is there a way to always use simple types (double, string or null) instead? Do I need a custom converter?

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Root 
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> attributes {get;set;} 
}
                    
public class Program
{
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"attributes\":{\"value1\":\"something\",\"value2\":123}}";
        var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
        
        Console.WriteLine(o.attributes["value1"].GetType()); 
        // prints: System.Text.Json.JsonElement     
    }
}
```